# Cannot start Postgresql-9.5 service on CentOS 6.7

Tags: postgresql, replication, centos6, database-administration

1) Not able to start service Postgresql-9.5 on

```
[root@bmipgsqlt3 /]# /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.5 restart
Stopping postgresql-9.5 service:                           [  OK  ]
Starting postgresql-9.5 service:                           [FAILED]
```

Not able to start the postgres service after making changes following replication configuration from:
http://www.unixmen.com/setup-postgresql-replication-centos/

```
bash-4.1$ pg_basebackup -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data -h 10.200.231.151 -U repluser
NOTICE:  WAL archiving is not enabled; you must ensure that all required WAL segments are copied through other means to complete the backup
```

To get rid of this notice, I need to change WAL_archiving setting from postgres.conf. However, to make that change effective I will need to restart the service which I am not able to do now.

This is slave server and everything is working fine on the master server. I am able to start and stop the service on Master.

PS: I am at the step where I stopped the service on Slave server and executed pg_basebackup

2) I dont see recovery.conf file in /data/ folder after I backuped the data

```
[root@bmipgsqlt3 /]# cd /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/
[root@bmipgsqlt3 data]# ls
backup_label  pg_dynshmem    pg_multixact  pg_stat      PG_VERSION
base          pg_hba.conf    pg_notify     pg_stat_tmp  pg_xlog
global        pg_ident.conf  pg_replslot   pg_subtrans  postgresql.auto.conf
pg_clog       pg_log         pg_serial     pg_tblspc    postgresql.conf
pg_commit_ts  pg_logical     pg_snapshots  pg_twophase
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the server log output of the server that you are trying to start.

I suspect you were confused by what `pg_basebackup` is trying to tell you.  Your basebackup is incomplete without additional WAL segments, and the slave server you are setting up won't start because of that.

What you should do is either run `pg_basebackup` with the option `-X stream`, or set up archiving on the *master* server.  To set up archiving on the master, you might have to restart it.  But you don't need to restart the slave server right now, because the slave server you have built is unusable at this point and can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks @PeterEisentraut. I tried to run below command and it gave this message:


`bash-4.1$ pg_basebackup -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data -w -R --xlog-     method=stream -h 10.200.231.151 -U repluser
pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: FATAL:  number of requested standby connections exceeds max_wal_senders (currently 1)`



Again to change max_wal_senders I need to go to Postgres.conf and need to restart the service. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In `pg_log` file under path `/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_log` After executing below `pg_basebackup` WITHOUT -X stream:

**2016-05-26 15:11:55.389 EDT >LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2016-05-26 12:34:31 EDT
< 2016-05-26 15:11:55.502 EDT >LOG:  invalid checkpoint record
< 2016-05-26 15:11:55.502 EDT >FATAL:  could not locate required checkpoint record
< 2016-05-26 15:11:55.502 EDT >HINT:  If you are not restoring from a backup, try removing the file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/backup_label".
< 2016-05-26... >LOG:  startup process (PID 5269) exited with exit code 1**

Comment: After executing pg_basebackup as above with -X stream option log file shows


**< 2016-05-26 21:14:57.621 EDT >FATAL:  number of requested standby connections exceeds max_wal_senders (currently 1)
< 2016-05-26 21:14:57.623 EDT >LOG:  could not send data to client: Connection reset by peer
< 2016-05-26 21:14:57.623 EDT >ERROR:  base backup could not send data, aborting backup
< 2016-05-26 21:14:57.623 EDT >LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
< 2016-05-26 21:14:57.623 EDT >FATAL:  connection to client lost**